# XSL: test against key

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I have a large list of names (with biographical details) in an file `people.xml`. These people appear in random places in another file  `corpus.xml`. They are 'tied together' with an `@xml:id`.

Thus in the `people.xml` file, there are entries like

```
<person xml:id="john_foo"/>
<person xml:id="ann_foo"/>
<person xml:id="sally_foo"/>
...
```

And in the `corpus.xml`file, we can find these same xml:ids (anywhere in the document) under `@nameref`

```
<corpus>
<p>
  <persName nameref="#john_foo" role="a"/>
  <persName nameref="#ann_foo" role="g"/>
  <s>
     <persName nameref="#john_foo" role="g"/>
  </s>
</p>
<p>
  <persName nameref="#sally_foo" role="a"/>
  <d>
     <persName nameref="#sally_foo" role="p"/>
  </d>
</p>
...
<corpus>
```

I want to test (using XSL 3.0, Saxon) each `people.xml//@xml:id` for existence in `corpus.xml/corpus//persName/@nameref` BUT only when `@role` matches a certain value. In this case, I only want to return a 'positive result' if `@role="a"`

I'm trying to use keys to do this, but it's not returning anything:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="3.0">

<xsl:key name="namerefs" match="corpus" use=".//persName[@role='a']"/>

<xsl:param name="documt" select="doc('corpus.xml')"/>

<xsl:template match="person">
  <!-- test if exists @xml:id + @role="a" -->
  <xsl:if test="key($namerefs, concat('#',@xml:id) ,$documt")>if found, do something here</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I think I am not accessing the right node in the key?

Many thanks in advance.

nb. Updated for various typos

Comment: What is `doc()`? Also, `key($namerefs, ...)` cannot possibly be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:key name="persName" match="persName" use="substring-after(@nameref, '#')" />
  <xsl:param name="corpusDoc" select="document('corpus.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//person" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:if test="key('persName', @xml:id, $corpusDoc)[@role = 'a']">
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

outputs

```
<person xml:id="john_foo"/>
<person xml:id="sally_foo"/>
```

You can move the predicate `[@role = 'a']` from the `<xsl:if>` to the `<xsl:key>`. That would work, but I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: FYI it's also possible to use keys in the match expression: `<xsl:template match="person[key('persName', @xml:id, $corpusDoc)[@role = 'a']]">`. Can save the `<xsl:if>`.